# Arguments passed to WorkerScript source

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I need to load documents which filepath is provided by a **FileDialog.** The document are rather long to load so I want to display a **BusyIndicator** while loading the docs. In order to get the **UI spinned** while loading my doc I need to load my docs in a **WorkerScript**. Now I need to provide my filepath to the functions in the **.js** file pointed by **WorkerScript::source**. I could not find any way to do so.

Any idea?

Here is my source code:

```
WorkerScript
{
    id: importScanWorkerScript
    source: "script.js"
}

FileDialog
{
    id: importScanDialog
    visible: false
    title: "Import a [scan] file"
    folder: "/home/arennuit/Desktop/living_room_traj0n_scannedScene"
    nameFilters: [ "STL files (*stl)" ]
    selectedNameFilter: "STL files (*stl)"
    onAccepted:
    {
        importScanDialog.visible = false;
        busyIndicator.running = true;
        uiController.onImportScanDevMenuClicked(importScanDialog.fileUrl);
        busyIndicator.running = false;
    }
}

BusyIndicator
{
    id: busyIndicator
    running: false
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WorkerScript` allows you to send custom object to a thread and also to get a custom object back, I guess the documentation is pretty clear. So the answer to your question is [WorkerScript.sendMessage()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-workerscript.html#sendMessage-method). In the simple example below the `WorkerScript` receives random number of iterations from `main.qml` and so generates and sent back generated text, displayed by `main.qml`. The GUI doesn't freeze while waiting:

**main.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    id: window
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    ScrollView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true
        TextArea {
            id: myText
            text: ""
            enabled: false
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var cnt = 1000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
        myText.text = "Please wait, generating text (" + cnt + " characters) ...";
        myWorker.sendMessage({count: cnt});
    }

    WorkerScript {
        id: myWorker
        source: "script.js"
        onMessage: {
            myText.text = messageObject.reply;
            myText.enabled = true;
            spinner.running = false;
        }
    }

    BusyIndicator {
        id: spinner
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        running: true
    }
}
```

**script.js**

```js
function pause(millis)
{
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { 
        curDate = new Date(); 
    } while((curDate - date) < millis);
}

WorkerScript.onMessage = function(message) {
    var txt = "";
    var count = message.count;
    for(var i = 0;i < count;i ++)
    {
        var ch = 97 + Math.round(Math.random() * 25);
        txt += String.fromCharCode(ch);
        var eol = Math.round(Math.random() * 30);
        if(eol === 1)
            txt += "\r\n";
        else if(!(eol % 5))
            txt += " ";
        pause(10);
    }
    WorkerScript.sendMessage({ 'reply': txt })
}
```

Comment: I really don't get it, the secondary thread is created, but [from here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-workerscript.html#restrictions) it seems it cannot access QML item properties, methods and attributes (and I was able to double checked this in my code). My controller is a C++ QObject imported in the primary thread context (as all my computations happen in C++). What's the point of the secondary thread if I cannot access my controller? I guess there is something I have missed...

Comment: You answered the initial question. I have written a more specific question for the [access to the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752428/workerscript-access-to-controller-class).