# WorkerScript access to Controller class

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a BusyIndicator which should spin while heavy computations are happening and stop when the computations are done.

I thought WorkerScript was the right way to go but but [from here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-workerscript.html#restrictions), it seems that the secondary (computation thread) in the .js file does not have access to the objects of the primary .qml thread.

This is problematic as all my computations are performed through a Controller C++ defined QObject instantiated by the primary thread.

Here is my code:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

import LcQml 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: window

    UiController
    {
        id: uiController
    }

    WorkerScript
    {
        id: importScanWorkerScript
        source: "importScanWorkerScript.js"
        onMessage:
        {
            busyIndicator.running = false;
        }
    }

    FileDialog
    {
        id: importScanDialog
        visible: false
        title: "Import a [scan] file"
        folder: "MyScannedScenesFolder"
        nameFilters: [ "STL files (*stl)" ]
        selectedNameFilter: "STL files (*stl)"
        onAccepted:
        {
            importScanWorkerScript.sendMessage({'filepath': importScanDialog.fileUrl})
            busyIndicator.running = true;
        }
    }

    BusyIndicator
    {
        id: busyIndicator
        running: false
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

**importScanWorkerScript.js**

```
WorkerScript.onMessage = function(message)
{
    uiController.onImportScanDevMenuClicked(message.filepath);
    WorkerScript.sendMessage()
}
```

**Pb:** uiController is not defined in **importScanWorkerScript.js**.

Should I understand that WorkerScript can only handle simple situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already noticed, `WorkerScript` cannot access UI controls. But your separate thread can "talk" to the main UI thread using messages. As for me that works exactly as in all other languages/frameworks. Just send a message from the thread whenever you want to update UI or your object.
For example:

```
WorkerScript.onMessage = function(message) {
    WorkerScript.sendMessage({ 'action': 'start' })
    // do some heavy task here
    WorkerScript.sendMessage({ 'action': 'finish', 'data': somedata })
}
```

and so your main qml may look like this:

```
WorkerScript {
    id: myWorker
    source: "func.js"
    onMessage: {
        switch(messageObject.action)
        {
        case 'start':
            spinner.running = true;
            uiController.doSomething();
            break;
        case 'finish':
            spinner.running = false;
            uiController.doSomethingAnother();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With your proposal the uiController.doSomething() and uiController.doSomethingAnother() are handled in the UI thread, no? In my case it turns out that uiController.doSomething() and uiController.doSomethingAnother() are the actual heavy fonctions which should be computer in the background thread...

Comment: Ah, ok, now I see it. The best approach here is to run the heavy task using QThread in C++ code. There is no sense to run C++ task with Javascript code, although you cannot pass you object into WorkerScript.

Comment: I am not sure I understand that WorkerScript le useful for then... Who wants to perform heavy commutation in js? Anyway thanks a lot for your help!